# Merging two tables which have same and new columns

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, merge

I have two tables table1 with columns col1, col2, col3, col4, col8 and second table table2 with columns col1, col2, col3, col5, col6, col7.
I want to merge those table in one new table where data will be as col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8 respectively.

Is there any way in SQL or C# I can do?

Comment: yes, assuming cols 1,2,3 always equal each other.. what did you try

Comment: yes they are equal, I tried some queries like `CREATE TABLE Test_table as
  SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 FROM table1
    UNION
  SELECT col1, col2, col3, col5, col6, col7 FROM table2;`

Comment: then show what you tried, what issues you had - this site is not about doing all the work for you

Comment: Union is not what you want here. You need to join. Do we have a key value to join? I do not think you are looking for cartesian join.

Comment: You probably want a view

Comment: @I_am_Batman  col1, col2, col3, col4 are same , I can use them for join

Comment: Do you plan on no longer using the old tables?

Comment: except you dont have col4 in some of your data - so that doesnt sound right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want a view -- here is how you would make one on most platforms.

```
CREATE VIEW twotables AS
SELECT a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, a.col4, b.col5, b.col6, b.col7, a.col8 
FROM table1 a
JOIN table2 b ON a.col1=b.col1 and a.col2=b.col2 and a.col3=b.col3 and a.col4=b.col4
```

You may or may not want those columns in the join.

Another issue that many people have when they do something like this is they have different records for col1, col2, col3, and col4 in both tables.  Then you need to something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW twotables as
SELECT a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, a.col4, b.col5, b.col6, b.col7, a.col8 
FROM (select distinct col1, col2, col3, col4 from table1
      union 
      select distinct col1, col2, col3, col4 from table2
) as k
LEFT JOIN table1 a ON a.col1=k.col1 and a.col2=k.col2 and a.col3=k.col3 and a.col4=k.col4
LEFT JOIN table2 b ON b.col1=k.col1 and b.col2=k.col2 and b.col3=k.col3 and b.col4=k.col4
```

Here we first get a list of all "keys" and then we left join to the two tables.

Comment: does `create table as .. select..` work in sql server?

Comment: @vkp Read "CREATE VIEW"

Comment: @vkp what do you expect "create table as .. select" to do?  I don't think he wants a materialized view --- is that what you are suggesting?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a VIEW, then you can create a table via:

```
    WITH    Data
              AS ( SELECT   col1 ,
                            col2 ,
                            col3 ,
                            col4 ,
                            NULL AS col5 ,
                            NULL AS col6 ,
                            NULL AS col7 ,
                            col8
                   FROM     table1
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT   col1 ,
                            col2 ,
                            col3 ,
                            NULL AS col4 ,
                            col5 ,
                            col6 ,
                            col7 ,
                            NULL AS col8
                   FROM     table2
                 )
        SELECT  *
        INTO    table3
        FROM    Data;
```

Answer (score 0):

If columns of `table1 with col1, col2, col3` and `table2 with columns col1, col2, col3`.
Then you can write prepare a select query and leverage the power of `CTAS (Create Table As Select)`.
This will be something below:

```
CREATE table table3 
as 
SELECT 
T1.COL1,
T1.COL2,
T1.COL3,
COL4,
COL5,
COL6,
COL7,
COL8
FROM 
TABLE1 T1,
TABLE2 T2
WHERE
T1.COL1 = T2.COL1
AND T1.COL2 = T2.COL2
AND T1.COL3 = T2.COL3;
```